# Authenticating the user

Tags: authentication

I am developing an asp.net application in 3.5 where authentication is done using cookies. On the default page I am authenticating the user and setting some value in cookie.
Whenever I need to authenticate the user I just verify it from the cookie. If the user is not authorized then I redirect him to the default page for authentication.
Is this the correct way to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to authenticate users using Usernames & Passwords with roles and the like, I suggest using .NET's Forms Authentication: http://www.asp.net/Learn/Security/.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question on practice. I have done authentication using session variables before without any major issues. I do recommend using Forms Authentication and using the Membership class.

[MSDN Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998317.aspx)

Comment: I cannot use Sessions in my application.

Comment: Which is all fine and good. The forms auth is a better use of authentication anyways, IMHO.